# key bind command gives different output when called

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have this code. What i want to do is pretty simple, press return instead of clicking the button to get the text written in the entry but for some reason when I press enter I get a error and when I press the button I don't.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import LEFT, RIGHT


class App:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("App")
        root.geometry("300x150")

        self.labell=tk.Label(root)
        self.labell["justify"] = "center"
        self.labell["text"] = "label"
        self.labell.pack()

        self.entryy=tk.Entry(root)
        self.entryy.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.buttonn=tk.Button(root)
        self.buttonn["justify"] = "center"
        self.buttonn["text"] = "Button"
        self.buttonn["command"] = self.button_command
        self.buttonn.pack(side=RIGHT)

        # root.bind('<Return>', self.button_command)

    def button_command(self, dummy): 
        x = self.entryy.get()
        if App.count == 0:
            print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.bind("<Return>", app.button_command)
    root.mainloop()
```

In this case I wrote in the entry "hello".

```
line 31, in button_command
    x = self.entryy.get()
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'entryy'
hello
```

Also, as some of you might have noticed I wrote used `bind` twice, I am not sure where to put it, if inside the `__init__` or in the if statement.

Comment: [Bindings and Events](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events), [The Event class](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-handlers.html)

Comment: I think you meant to write `root.bind("<Return>", app.button_command)`.  Note the lowercase `app`.

Comment: @JohnGordon why should it be lowercase?

Comment: Because I assume you meant to refer `app` which is a specific _instance_ of the `App` class, instead of the class itself.  Otherwise why did you bother creating `app` in the first place?

Comment: @JohnGordon If I write `root.bind("<Return>", app.button_command)` inside the if and I comment the other bind i get another error:

`TypeError: button_command() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given)`

Comment: Add a second dummy argument to the method definition of `button_command`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have, then It works if i press return but gives an error whenever i press the button (`TypeError: button_command() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'dummy'`)

Comment: when i specify the function to call when the button is pressed I cant use the "()"  to give the second argument, so i don't see how adding a dummy argument would help.

Comment: if you have to add argument then use `lambda`  - `lambda: app.button_command(argument)`

Comment: your code works correctly on my Linux Mint - I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: if you want to use the same function in `bind` which runs it with `event` and with `command=` which runs it without `event` then you should use default value for `event`- like `event=None` - `def button_command(self, event=None):` - and then it will run correctly for both but you can't use `event` to get details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error but if you want to use the same function in `bind` (which runs it with `event`) and with `command=` (which runs it without `event`) then you should use default value for `event` - like `event=None` -

```
def button_command(self, event=None):
```

and then it will run correctly for both but you can't use `event` to get details. You would have to check `if event is not None:` (or `if event:`) before using it.

---

This code works for me on Linux Mint

I prefer `bind` hidden inside class. And `self.count` instead of `App.count`.

I would even hide `Tk()` and `mainloop` inside class.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App:
    
    def __init__(self, root):

        self.count = 0   

        root.title("App")
        root.geometry("300x150")

        self.labell = tk.Label(root, text="Label", justify="center")
        self.labell.pack()

        self.entryy = tk.Entry(root)
        self.entryy.pack(side='left')

        self.buttonn = tk.Button(root, text="Button", justify="center", command=self.button_command)
        self.buttonn.pack(side='right')

        root.bind('<Return>', self.button_command)

    def button_command(self, event=None): 
        x = self.entryy.get()
        if self.count == 0:
            print('x:', x, 'count:', self.count, 'event:', event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Info for all visitors: @serax checked it can be used `*args` to resolve problem with different number of arguments

```
def button_command(self, *args): 
    x = self.entryy.get()
    if self.count == 0:
        print('x:', x, 'count:', self.count, 'args:', args)
```

Comment: Oh i see. Do you think that `*args` would work instead of `event=None` ?

Comment: simply try `*args` and you will see if it works - I think it should work but I would have to try it to confirm it.